# What in the world am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> For you hate my feel,
>
> Yet I'm as strong as steel.
>
> You may think I weight a ton,
>
> But wait, I'm lighter than cotton!
>
> I bother so many, but marvel only a few.
>
> You can't see me, but I sometimes I come to you.

**What in the world am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **SPIDER SILK**

For You hate my feel.

> because of obvious reasons

Yet I'm as strong as steel.

You may think I weight a ton,

But wait I'm lighter than cotton,

> Properties of spider silk

I bother so many, but Marvel only a Few.

> Marvel here may be either Spiderman or just looks of a spider web

You can't see me, but I sometimes I come to you.

> is hard to see when it's not formed as web (single string) but I can't find a reasonable thing to say about 'I sometimes come to you' part

Comment: last point could refer to rot13(nppvqragnyyl jnyxvat vagb n jro)

Comment: Final clue: [ROT13](https://www.rot13.com/)(n fcvqre qebcf sebz gur prvyvat ol n fgenaq).

Comment: I don't foresee anyone thinking this weighs a ton.

Comment: +1 Correct answer and yes the last clue is correctly described by @EightAndAHalfTails.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it could be (a partial one)

> Grief / melancholy

As,

For You hate my feel.

> People do not like / hate being grief struck / melancholic

Yet I'm as strong as steel.

> it is one of the toughest feelings to overcome - a kind of metaphoric use here.

You may think I weight a ton,

> Usually grieved persons are heavy with feelings - another metaphoric use

But wait I'm lighter than cotton,

> It is just a feeling/ state of mind and hence - physically weightless.

I bother so many, but marvel only a Few.

> Many grieved souls bothered but few excelled in the form of poets / artistes etc.

You can't see me, but I sometimes I come to you.

> Obvious, occasionally we encounter this feeling.

Comment: A very creative answer but I don't think that I applied a lateral-thinking tag. Overall a nice answer but not the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

First time posting here, but I think its

> A hurricane/strong winds

For You hate my feel.

> being hit by strong winds is not at all pleasant

Yet I'm as strong as steel.

You may think I weight a ton,

> Strong winds are, well, strong, and feel like getting hit by a physical object

But wait I'm lighter than cotton,

> wind is just air after all

I bother so many, but marvel only a Few.

> nobody likes being near a hurricane, except for storm chasers

You can't see me, but I sometimes I come to you.

> you can't see air or wind but it can blow itself across large areas

Comment: Good attempt. But not the correct answer. A few of the hints as in the last few remain unexplained.